# CSV Filled Table (Via JS) Not Loading View In Browser Until Manual Refresh

Tags: javascript, csv, jekyll

So I'm really not a JS guy in the slightest, but wanted to basically render a CSV as table on my Jekyll site - I have this working with the following script.

Only problem is it never seems to load the table first time, I need to click refresh in the browser for it to appear - does anyone have any ideas as to what could be the cause of this?

```html
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        with(new XMLHttpRequest()) {
            onreadystatechange = cb;
            open('GET', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clintjb/A350-Tracking/main/flight_data_a350.csv', true);
            responseType = 'text';
            send();
        }
    }

function cb() {
    if (this.readyState === 4) document.getElementById('A350')
        .innerHTML = tbl(this.responseText);
}

function tbl(csv) {
    return csv.split('\n')
        .map(function(tr, i) {
            return '<tr><td>' +
                tr.replace(/,/g,'</td><td>') +
                '</td></tr>';
        })
        .join('\n');
}
</script>

<table border="0" style='font-size:50%' id="A350"></table>
```

Comment: What browser are you using? For me, on chrome, it works first try with the snippet.

Comment: Yep snippet works fine in Chrome or Firefox - seems once its embedded in the Jekyll HTML it requires a refresh - see here  https://clintbird.com/blog/ghactions-a350-flights-post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to recreate the issue on my machine. Your code worked fine for me, at least in chrome,
but one thing you could try is using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead of XMLHttpRequest. both worked for me

That would look something like the following

```
<script>
    fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/clintjb/A350-Tracking/main/flight_data_a350.csv'
    ).then((response) => {
        return response.text();
    }).then((text) => {
        document.getElementById('A350').innerHTML = tbl(text);
    })

    function tbl(csv) {
        return csv.split('\n')
            .map(function (tr, i) {
                return '<tr><td>' +
                    tr.replace(/,/g, '</td><td>') +
                    '</td></tr>';
            })
            .join('\n');
    }

</script>

<table border="0" style='font-size:50%' id="A350"></table>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi Mads,
Thanks for this - the code snippet is cleaner either way so have implemented it.... Both yours and mine seem to work when running as a standalone snippet but as said when I run this embedded in Jekyll it only appears after a refresh - you can see it hear as an example about 2/3 of the way down - https://clintbird.com/blog/ghactions-a350-flights-post

Comment: hmm, the table in the link works for me without any problems, at least in chrome
Does the console (open it  by pressing  F12) give you any errors when the table don't show op?

Comment: You can try to move the table above the script, as the Problem might be caused by The Script running before the table has loaded.

Comment: Ive tried moving the table above the script as well as moving the script further up the page - neither seem to work....

Answer (score 0):

So all the solutions (including my first proposal) actually worked. The issue in the end was actually a strange bug in the template used on the Jekyll site.

If you went directly to the page it rendered fine, if you refreshed it rendered fine - was only going via the menus which would than cause the rendering issue.

Due to this I changed the approach and used a GitHub actions to push the file each day - with the CSV in the same repo as the (e.g. like in _data/my_file.csv) you can access the data when the site builds as

```
{{ site.data.my_csv }}
```